# Clean Navigation in Compose using Compose Destinations Library

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am working in a Compose only project, I am wondering if there is a good solution for clean navigation (I feel like vm -> composable communication is ugly).

I want viewModel to decide about destination (ideally, vm should call navManager.navigate(LoginDestination)) and use Compose Destinations Library (https://github.com/raamcosta/compose-destinations)

I tried to search a few clean navigation repos on GitHub, but I have a problem implementing them since there are no examples using Compose Destinations library. I did make my own solution, but I assume it can be much cleaner.

```
@Composable
fun DestinationWithNav(
    navState: StateFlow<StateEventWithContent<NavigationState>>,
    navigator: DestinationsNavigator,
    consume: () -> Unit,
    screen: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val state by navState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    EventEffect(event = state, onConsumed = consume) {
        navigator.navigate(
            direction = it.direction,
            builder = it.builder
        )
    }


    screen()
}
```

Basically the function asks for `NavigationState` and navigates based on it.